# Solr: How to search for documents that have a word in the first X words of the document ?

Tags: solr

Is there a way to search for all document that include a word in the first 10 words of a certain field?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems odd to me. It might help if you provide more information about your larger goals. First `X` words is not typically a semantically useful way of thinking about Solr fields.

Comment: I am using Solr to hold data, not really text documents. So in my scenario every "word" is actually a machine generated token. Tokens have positions (just like a word has a position) and I am looking for a way to search for a token in the first 10 tokens. 

I just used the "first 10 words" example to make the description clear

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that it will always be the first ten words of a particular field that you are targeting, perhaps you could add a field to your `schema.xml` that just contains the first ten words of that field.

Comment: Right, that would work if the number 10 is known at design time. But in my case the user may choose distance.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the high-level problem that you are trying to solve. There must be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It would be really easy to write an analyzer with a parameter having the number of max tokens which would filter the remaining tokens making it reusable.
you can easily modify the schema.xml to copy the original field contents to this field and use this field for searching.

Comment: Here are a couple of good articles that walk through creating a custom Solr analyzer - 1. http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/ 2. http://java.dzone.com/news/writing-solr-analysis-filter

Comment: Thanks, but that would only work if the distance from the begining of the document is known at indexing time. In my case, the user decided as run time the distance allowed from the beginning of the document.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do it:

`public boolean doesWordExist(String word, String path) {`

```
    String line = null;
    int count = 0;
    String token = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(/*use filename filter here*/);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        count=0;
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[i].getName())));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && count < 10) {
                    StringTokenizer tknz = new StringTokenizer(line, "");
                    while (tknz.hasMoreTokens() && count < 10 /* variable */) {
                        token = tknz.nextToken();
                        if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }// if
    }//for
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting how to parse files, question is about Solr index